# How can i fix the true or false in this code?

Tags: swift, list, loops, for-loop

Write a function isIncreasing that takes a list of Ints and returns true if numbers are in increasing (equals OK) order. An empty list should result in true.

```
func isIncreasing(_ l: [Int]) -> Bool {
    
    var flagreturn=true
    if l.count == 0 {
        flagreturn=true
        
        
    } else {
        for i: Int in l {
            if l[i] < l[i + 1] {
              flagreturn=true
                
            }
            else{
                flagreturn=false
                
            }
           
        
            
        }
    }
    return flagreturn

}
```

Not sure if I implemented the true and false correctly in the code.

Comment: You're setting your `flagreturn` on every step of the loop, so whatever you set on the last iteration will over-write anything that came from previous iteration.

Comment: Once you detect a non-incremental result, you should break the loop - but as stated, start with assumption it is (incrementing) and when you find a condition where it’s not, set the flag to false and break out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the sequence with itself dropping the first element and check if it all satisfy a condition like $0 <= $1:

```
func isIncreasing(_ l: [Int]) -> Bool {
    zip(l, l.dropFirst()).allSatisfy { $0 <= $1 }
}
```

---

```
isIncreasing([1,2])        // true
isIncreasing([0,1,1,2])    // true
isIncreasing([0,1,1,2,1])  // false
```

Expanding on that you can extend sequence constraining its elements to Comparable an d create a generic property like `areInIncreasingOrder`:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
    var areInIncreasingOrder: Bool {
        zip(self, dropFirst()).allSatisfy { $0 <= $1 }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
[1,2].areInIncreasingOrder               // true
[1,2].dropFirst(2).areInIncreasingOrder  // true
[0,1,1,2].areInIncreasingOrder           // true
[0,1,1,2,1].areInIncreasingOrder         // false
```

Comment: Great solution! Absolutely sure I like it! It's takes more memory than my solution, but it's code is elegant :)

Comment: @Andrew___Pls_Support_UA: No, it doesn't. zip() returns a (lazily evaluated) sequence, not an array.

Comment: @MartinR doublechecked, you're absolutely right. Thanks for a new knowledge